# Sending an email using javamail as if it were being sent from gmail

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

I'm developing a web application that uses `javamail` to send email messages and it works correctly.

The problem is that I don't get the email that I'm sending in the sent mail folder in the gmail account which I connect to, also I don't get bounced email as it happens if I try to send the email via gmail application.

I doubt this is due to security restrictions from javamail and cannot be done, as it would be much faster to get a possible spam list from an email server than doing it manually.but if it's for security reasons it would just be much better just not to bounce emails.

How can I use javamail as if sending the mails from gmail.com, getting the sent message in the sent mail folder and bounced mails in inbox folder?

Comment: Do you use gmail's SMTP server?  Because if you do, sent mail should get added to your gmail account - see [here](http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server)

Comment: I'm using this:                                                       Properties props = new Properties();  
       props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtp.gmail.com");  so I think I'm using it

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I don't get the email that I'm sending in the sent mail folder

Sending a mail via SMTP does not copy it to a sent folder automatically. Your sending application would have to make an IMAP connection after the SMTP connection and copy the message into the sent folder.

> also I don't get bounced email

Make sure the Evelope Sender Address ("Return-Path") is set to the Gmail Adress you're using to send the messages.

Comment: You cannot directly set the Return-Path: header, though; you need to be able to control the actual SMTP envelope sender.

Comment: You can set the mail.smtp.from property to the address you want to use for the SMTP envelope (or use the SMTPMessage class), but it's going to default to the From address for the message you're sending, and Gmail probably won't let you set it to another address unless you follow [these instructions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en).